# Access to MSK with IAM auth via NLB listeners

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, amazon-iam, aws-msk

There is AWS MSK 3.1.1 setup with 3 brokers, one in each availability zone.
There is NLB.
There is kafka-integrations-dev.com DNS name for NLB.

NLB has 3 listeners for IAM brokers:

- TLS:7200 -> target group #1 TLS:9098 -> IP of broker #1, port 9098.
- TLS:7201 -> target group #2 TLS:9098 -> IP of broker #2, port 9098.
- TLS:7202 -> target group #3 TLS:9098 -> IP of broker #2, port 9098.

There is SSL/TLS certificate with `kafka-integrations-dev.com` domain configured for every mentioned listeners.

Is it possible to connect to MSK cluster with IAM auth by `kafka-integrations-dev.com:7200`, `kafka-integrations-dev.com:7201`, `kafka-integrations-dev.com:7202` as bootstrap servers?

Now we are getting error `Hostname verification failed`.

I found [Making AWS MSK public using NLB and IAM authentication - Hostname verification failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69617259/making-aws-msk-public-using-nlb-and-iam-authentication-hostname-verification-f)
The author stated that connection to MSK via NLB using IAM auth was not supported in 2021.

Comment: It seems really odd to have a NLB in front of kafka. Your clients connect to individual brokers directly, they should not be load balanced.

Comment: @jordanm check the article please https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/how-goldman-sachs-builds-cross-account-connectivity-to-their-amazon-msk-clusters-with-aws-privatelink/. There is pattern #2, which is used to build cross-account connectivity between client and MSK cluster.

Comment: That configuration has a NLB *per* broker.

Comment: @jordanm oh you are right

Comment: there are two patterns. Pattern1 has NLB per broker, but pattern 2 has a listener per broker. Both patterns won't work for IAM. Will post in answer full explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided solution with NLB will work for TLS and SASL-SCRAM, and won't work for mTLS and SASL-IAM. Since you are asking specifically about IAM, here are some details.

When you initiate SASL-IAM protocol, you are signing your request including endpoint. Since your client is using custom domain name, broker (with different domain name) will reject such request. So, even though you can terminate TLS at NLB, you cannot re-sign the request, it would break the mechanism of IAM authentication which signs the request with Role arn, and endpoint URLs.